# How to use Zend_Barcode library in Magento 2?

Tags: barcode, magento2

I want to generate a bar code using Zend library and I have this error:

> Class 'Namespace\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Zend_Barcode' not found in
>   'Namespace\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment.php'.

This is my code with error:

```
$imageResource = Zend_Barcode::draw(
            'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
        );
```

In Magento 1.9 works but when I change it on Magento 2 doesn't work. I don't know how to include `Zend_Barcode` class of Zend Library in my Shippment class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also import `Zend_Barcode` class at the top of your class file:

```
use Zend_Barcode;
```

Then, your code will work as normal:

```
$imageResource = Zend_Barcode::draw(
        'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
    );
```

OR, you can directly instantiate the object of the class. For this, you don't need to import the class but have to use "backslash" infront of the `Zend_Barcode` class name.

```
$imageResource = \Zend_Barcode::draw(
        'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
    );
```

**Reference:** PHP Documentation on [Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)